# echo all pages with each pages unique title from directory/folder

Tags: php

I have a folder in the main root, News. In that folder, I have 10 pages, each one has a unique page title:

/news/Today-is-cold-outside.php title = Today is Cold

/news/Watch-out-for-the-smelly-frogs.php title = Smelly Toads

I can get the code below to work so that it will fetch each page and provide a link to each page with the page name $file, example: Today-is-cold-outside.php, not $title = Today is Cold.

How can I get the page to display the specific Page Title for each link $title?

I know I have $file listed below instead of $title in the link, I left it in there so you can see where I am wanting to display the title and that if you test it, it will show you that it is getting the $file=pages from the directory/folder news.

Thanks in advance, I have been working for 2 days on this and cant find a solution.

```
<?php
$handle = opendir('news');
$dom    = new DOMDocument();

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
if ($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php') {

    if($dom->loadHTMLFile($urlpage)) {
        $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
        if ($list->length > 0) {
            $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
        }
    }

    echo "<a href='news/$file'>$file</a>";
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: where is $urlpage  coming from?

Comment: on my original code attached to the question, my error log shows: Empty string supplied as input in 31 - which is the loadHTMLFile

Comment: where is $urlpage coming from?

Comment: it is coming from any page located within news folder/directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $file = Today-is-cold-outside.php

And you want $title to = Today is Cold

Do this:

```
$title = $file;
$title = str_replace('-',' ',$title);
$title = str_replace('.php','',$title);
echo $title;
```

This will convert dashes to spaces, and remove the .php extension.

If you like my answer I can also convert each word from lowercase into uppercase as well as limit the max number of words to 3 if you want.

Try this out:

```
<?php
$handle = opendir('news');
$dom    = new DOMDocument();

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
if ($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php') {

    if($dom->loadHTMLFile($urlpage)) {
        $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
        if ($list->length > 0) {
            $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
        }
    }
    $title = $file;
$title = str_replace('-',' ',$title);
$title = str_replace('.php','',$title);

echo '<a href="blog/'.$file.'">';
echo $title;
echo '</a>';

} 
}
?>
```

---

```
 <?php
 $handle = opendir('blog');
 $dom    = new DOMDocument();

 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
     $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
     if ($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php') {
        if($dom->loadHTMLFile('blog/'.$file)) {
           $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
           if ($list->length > 0) {
              $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
           }
     }

     echo "<a href='blog/$file'>$title</a><br/>";
 }
}
?>
<?php 
$title = $file;
$title = str_replace('-',' ',$title);
$title = str_replace('.php','',$title);

echo '<a href="blog/'.$file.'">';
echo $title;
echo '</a>'; ?>
```

Comment: @ michael d - can you show me where this would apply in my code? I just tried it and it did not work.

Comment: sorry, but no. I even tried changing the echo. displays nothing.

Comment: if you echo $file does it give you a value like "Today-is-cold-outside.php"? If so this code I gave you should work. If $file doesn't have a value then remove my code. When you echo $title does that have a value? If so, then we shouldn't have used "$title = $file". Remove that line. If $title doesn't have a value then perhaps you should be using $urlpage or $list. It's hard for me to say because I can't see the file you are opening.

Comment: yes the $file returns a link and value of "Today-is-cold-outside.php"

Comment: If $file returns that value then the code I gave you should work almost 100% certainly. I edited it. Try out the second iteration of the code. $title should return a value. If something glitches then play around with it or let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try nodeValue

`$title = $list->item(0)->nodeValue`

change

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file)
```

and

```
  echo "<a href='blog/$file'>$title</a>";
```

Comment: i tried that, it does not work. the blog/$file does link to the correct page, it just does not show the title, if i put blog/$file'>$title - nothing echos, its blank

Comment: `var_dump(title = $list->item(0))` and paste it here

Comment: thanks. i tried that already and it did not work. i cant figure out why it will not use $file in place of $urlpage to get the source.

Comment: what did the dump output?

Comment: make sure you have the right path for loadHTMLFile to load the file

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $handle = opendir('news');
 $dom    = new DOMDocument();

 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
     $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
     if ($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php') {
        if($dom->loadHTMLFile('news/'.$file)) {
           $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
           if ($list->length > 0) {
              $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
           }
     }

     echo "<a href='news/$file'>$title</a><br/>";
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$handle = opendir('news');
$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$title = '';
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
if ($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php') {
    if($dom->loadHTMLFile('news/'.$file)) {
        $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
        if ($list->length > 0) {
            $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
        }
    }

    echo "<a href='news/$file'>$file</a>";
    echo $title;
} 
}

?>
```

my directory name is "news"

Comment: thanks, i tried that as well, i updated the code to show , news instead of blog as the directory/folder

Comment: not to required dir name is news you can wrote your directory name which you want title file